# Easy way to move between full-screen Windows 10 guest and Ubuntu 18.04 host in VirtualBox using keyboard?

Tags: 18.04, unity, virtualbox, windows

I have a Windows 10 virtual machine, which I run in full-screen mode, with two virtual screens corresponding to my two physical screens. This is running on VirtualBox 6.1, under Ubuntu 18.04 (Unity) as the host OS.

When I am using my host OS, I often alt-tab into my virtual machine, which is very annoying, since I can't alt-tab back out again, and I have to reach for the mouse if I want to get back to where I was.

I thought that a good solution might be to use the 'workspaces' feature, and use alt-ctrl-LEFT and alt-ctrl-RIGHT to switch back and forth between host and guest. That doesn't work either, because these keystrokes are captured by VirtualBox as soon as I land in the VM (even though they typically don't do anything), and can't be handled by the host OS.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a nice way to overcome this, and get smooth switching between host and guest without using the mouse? Is there a way for VirtualBox to 'un-capture' specific keystrokes, and pass them back tot he host OS? I'd appreciate any thoughts/suggestions!

Comment: I found this relevant post: https://superuser.com/questions/108785/getting-host-to-capture-certain-key-presses-in-virtualbox (but it's not a 'perfect answer')

Comment: This is about VBox itself, not really Ubuntu or Unity. @jdpipe's comment leads to the best answer -- `Host Key` pauses keyboard capturing in the guest, which will allow using the keyboard "normally" in the host OS.

Comment: Thanks @l3l_aze, it wasn't clear to me that it *had* to be a VBox issue. After all, Ubuntu/Unity/something may be 'choosing' to pass events down to VBox, and may have the discretion of capturing some events on the way through. Where the problem lies depends a bit on the architecture, which isn't obvious to me...

Comment: No problem, and sorry - I didn't realize you were the OP and the comment, lol. The keyboard capturing is from VBox and can be changed in it's settings (as mentioned in the answers/comments of the question you linked), but it's not necessary if you're okay with the default host key. On Mac it was easy because the default host key is Cmd, so we can just press Cmd and then Cmd + Tab to tab out of the guest.